# Find out when a follower starts following me again on Twitter

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to see on what day another Twitter account starts following me?

I got a notification that a Twitter account has started following me, and there were two accounts - one that already was in my followers list for quite a long time.

I'm interested to know if that account unfollowed and followed me again.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign up for a service like social bro, which provides this functionality, as well as other reports.

www.socialbro.com

It isn't possible just using Twitter.